# Best way to index a string column for full string compare

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, ssms

My database is MS SQL 2008, and I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

I have a NVARCHAR(MAX) field that store a string called INTERNALDATA, that store data like this "SOME_NAME:SOME_ID", don't ask me why I just don't make another int column with SOME_ID, this is the way the project got setup and I can't change it now.

So now I need to do comparison on this field, thank god it's not sub-string comparision.  It's full column comparison like this:

```
INTERNALDATA = "Bill:5"
```

Now as you can imagine, this is really slow, what index should I use or changing the column type to make it faster?

PS:  The actual data stored in this field is not expected to be longer than maybe 100 chars long, maybe I should change NVARCHAR(MAX) to NVARCHAR(100)?

Answer (score 0):

Direct indexing of `nvarchar(max)` column is not possible, since index key is limited to 900 bytes.

Cutting column down to `nvarchar(100)` (if it is known that column will never contain longer values) and its further indexing seems fine solution.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a go and see how much it improves, thanks

Answer (score 0):

One common way to index long strings for equality searches is to index hash sum (e.g., md5) and then compare on *both* columns (the original raw value as well as the hash sum).

In SQL Server you can use HASHBYTES, for example: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx (has a 8000 bytes limit itself, however).

The reason to compare both columns (original and hash) is to protect against false positives in case there is a collision in the hash function. You might even gain performance by using only a part of the hash-value (not all bits) to keep the index smaller (mileage depends on you data).

**EDIT**

The maintainance of the index on the md5 sum can be done by SQL Server using a computed column (that's indexed): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx

This concept is often referred to as [function based indexing](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/functions).

Comment: Doesn't work if the data update which I suspect this case will do once in a while.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu Sorry, I guess I should have mentioned function based indexing. Does it now makes more sense for you?